# Mongoose-encryption Failure, Page keeps rolling

Tags: node.js, npm, encryption

I am having a problem with an npm package called 'mongoose-encryption'. Here is my code.

```
main().catch((err) => console.log(err));

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/userEncryptedDB', { useNewUrlParser: true });
}

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

const secret = 'xxs4Ox4nSKSVnJzIxzy+es6ouOmoMcqcarAnEVRP26Q=';

userSchema.plugin(encrypt, {secret: secret, encryptedFields: ['password']});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Now, if I don't use the package, registration and logging in to the website works properly but if I use the plug in, it says "You are never registered!" even though I register for the email and password...

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({email: email, password: password}, (err, user) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            if(user){
                console.log('You are already registered!');
                res.render('secrets');
            } else {
                console.error('You are never registered!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I started computer stopped database, restarted it. Registration is successfully done but when I try to login page keeps rolling... If I dont use mongoose-encryption, login page works fine once I enter password.

I can clearly see that the new username gets added to the database like so:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("616a4aa45dfbf877d9f92468"), "email" : "aras@aras.com", "_ct" : BinData(0,"YbVYW9Pi6dz1yqRD7XgcEyEp48lLGVjp3J40ZgxGt/YuA8+eyiyebMaO9AGdygBj6A=="), "_ac" : BinData(0,"YQiV2QvS9AyrE1hjm81x5U8K6+0lT8h1ruxtCEZv/iwZWyJfaWQiLCJfY3QiXQ=="), "__v" : 0 }
```

But then when I try to login, it fails to retrieve password. Password I use here in this case is "1".

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the collection (first save it somewhere for later use) and try again. It will work!